# Multiple condition in group by mongodb

Tags: mongodb, group-by, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, conditional-operator

I have data like this in a database:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5ec4e40a7c89c96c7c3818f0"),
  "lob" : "DIGITAL_STORE",
  "paymentMode" : "NET_BANKING",
  "pgStatus" : "PG_SUCCESS",
  "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-05-20T08:02:18.566Z"),
  "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-07-22T18:57:29.915Z"),
  "updatedBy" : "ONLINE_CHANNEL",
  "_class" : "com.airtel.payments.pg.commons.persistence.PgTransactionDetails"
},
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5ec4e40a7c89c96c7c3818f0"),
  "lob" : "DIGITAL_STORE",
  "paymentMode" : "NET_BANKING",
  "pgStatus" : "PG_FAILED",
  "createdAt" : ISODate("2020-05-20T08:02:18.566Z"),
  "updatedAt" : ISODate("2020-07-22T18:57:29.915Z"),
  "updatedBy" : "ONLINE_CHANNEL",
  "_class" : "com.airtel.payments.pg.commons.persistence.PgTransactionDetails"
}
```

I need to get data from mongodb where I can fetch count of success and failure in one document grouped by LOB & Payment mode.

I tried something like this, but lob and payment mode segregation not coming.

```
db.getCollection('transactionDetails').aggregate([
  {$project: {
    Success: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$pgStatus", "PG_SUCCESS" ]}, 1, 0]},
    Failed: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$pgStatus", "PG_FAILED"]}, 1, 0]}
  }},
  {$group: {
    _id: {Lob:"$lob",Mode:"$paymentMode"},
    Success: {$sum: "$Success"},
    Failed: {$sum: "$Failed"}
  }}
]);
```

I can do this separately but not able to get in single document both count of success and failure transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have used $project and you have projected one field only and other fields are no longer available for next pipeline,

You can add other fields in `$project` or you can use `$addFields` instead of `$project`,

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/6EtxK4F-ml9)

---

or you can try inside all operations in `$group`,

```
db.getCollection('transactionDetails').aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: { Lob: "$lob", Mode: "$paymentMode" },
      Success: {
        $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$pgStatus", "PG_SUCCESS"] }, 1, 0] }
      },
      Failed: {
        $sum: { $cond: [{ $eq: ["$pgStatus", "PG_FAILED"] }, 1, 0] }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/WpPeiIhlDcL)